# Oracle sql using subquery to group multiple row result into one row

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I was using a LISTAGG which someone here helped but after a few select field, I started to get an ORA error. I would rather use an Oracle subquery to group multiple row results into one row. In the past, I have used STUFF in sqlserver to do this, how would I do this on Oracle.

I have the following query

```
select d.id, d.name, d.date_sale, d.address, d.city, d.state, d.zipcode, d.description, d.explanation, d.received_date, 
       SELECT (dd.my_id, dd.customer_name, dd.category, dd.transaction_date, ';' 
       ) AS GROUPED_COLUMNS
from table1 d
left join table2 dd on d.id = dd.my_id
where d.id =1 and d.isActive =1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select d.* 
       (select list_agg(dd.my_id || dd.customer_name || dd.category || dd.transaction_date, ';') within group (order by transaction_date)
        from table2 dd
        where d.id = dd.my_id
       ) AS GROUPED_COLUMNS
from table1 d
where d.id = 1 and d.isActive = 1
```